# Place an Analyzer on a a specific array item in a nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping

```
"mappings":{
   "properties":{
     "name": {
         "type": "text"
       },
     "age": {
        "type": "integer" 
      },
     "customProps":{
       "type" : "nested",
       "properties": {
         "key":{
           "type": "keyword"
         },
         "value": {
           "type" : "keyword"
         }
        }
       }
      } 
     }
```

example data

```
{
  "name" : "person1",
  "age" : 10,
  "customProps":[
   {"hairColor":"blue"},
   {"height":"120"}
  ]
},
{
  "name" : "person2",
  "age" : 30,
  "customProps":[
    {"jobTitle" : "software engineer"},
    {"salaryAccount" : "AvGhj90AAb"}
  ]
}
```

so i want to be able to search for document by salary account case insensitive, i am also searching using wild card
example query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "customProps",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                 "must": [
                   { "match": { "customProps.key": "salaryAccount" } },
                   { "wildcard": { "customProps.value": "*AvG*"
                   }
                 }
               ]}}}}]}}}
```

i tried adding analyzer with PUT using the following syntax

```
{
  "settings":{
    "index":{
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "analyzer_case_insensitive" : {
            "tokenizer":"keyword",
            "filter":"lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
    "people":{
      "properties":{
        "customProps":{
          "properties":{
            "value":{
              "type": "keyword",
              "analyzer": "analyzer_case_insensitive"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

im getting the following error

> "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
> "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [people: {properties={customProps={properties={value={analyzer=analyzer_case_insensitive, type=keyword}}}}}]"

any idea how to do the analyzer for the salary account object in the array when it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use case is quite clear, that you want to search on the value of `salaryAccount` only when this key exists in `customProps` array.

There are some issues with your mapping definition :

1. You cannot define a custom analyzer for `keyword` type field, instead you can use a normalizer
2. Based on the mapping definition you added at the beginning of the question, it seems that you are using elasticsearch version 7.x. But the second mapping definition that you provided, in that you have added mapping type also (i.e `people`), which is deprecated in 7.x
3. There is no need to add the `key` and `value` fields in the index mapping.

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
PUT myidx
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "customProps": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

You need to use [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html), to check whether a field exists or not. And [`case_insensitive` param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#wildcard-query-field-params) in Wildcard query is available since elasticsearch version 7.10. If you are using a version below this, then you need to use a [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html), to achieve case insensitive scenarios.

```
POST myidx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "customProps",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "customProps.salaryAccount"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "customProps.salaryAccount.keyword": {
                        "value": "*aVg*",
                        "case_insensitive": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

****Search Result:****

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myidx",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "person2",
          "age" : 30,
          "customProps" : [
            {
              "jobTitle" : "software engineer"
            },
            {
              "salaryAccount" : "AvGhj90AAb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: hi, sorry i was a bit busy with something, i ended up changing the mapping template adding a normalizer on all the custom props values, however i can confirm that most of what you said is right, give me some time and i will test everything you wrote, thanks for the reply